# Counting multiple criteria

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, countif

I'm trying to count multiple criteria and got the code to work somehow with SUMPRODUCT.

```
Range("i2") = [SUMPRODUCT(($CZ$2:$CZ$61410="condition 1")*($DD$2:$DD$61410="condition 2")*($CU$2:$CU$61410=$A$2 <-/date/)*($CY$2:$CY$61410="condition 3"))]
```

There's around 40 colums with different conditions. So I have to code for each condition. But that's not really working for me, because I have to do the same thing for the whole month.

**Explanation**

Cells `A2` to `A32` hold dates, let's say from 1st of August 'til 31 of August.
Raw data table (on the same sheet) has dates on the `CU` column (might be 60000+ lines).
Column `CZ`, `DD`, `CY`, etc. have conditions that have to be met to be counted.

**Question**

What I want to do is if the date in column `CU` = the date in `A2` then it will be counted to row 2, if the date in column `CU` = the date in `A3` then it will be counted to row 3.

That way I can write one code for the whole month, not each day separately.

Answer (score 2):

I offer first a solution of a formula (WorksheetFunction if preferred) of this type:

```
=COUNTIFS(CZ:CZ,"=1",DD:DD,"=2",CY:CY,"=3", ... CU:CU,"="&A2)
```

and an image showing what this results in (the yellow cell) depending upon the date chosen:

[image: SO18505472 example]

This counts the number of instances, on the date chosen in A2, that match the hard-coded criteria displayed in Row1 for illustrative purposes.

Without the hard-coding of criteria but with possibly a slightly better 'match' to the OP and with more examples:

[image: SO18505472 second example]

Apart from the highlighting, the contents of `C6` were entered via the following macro:

```
Sub Macro1()
    Range("C6").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNTIFS(C[101],R1C[101],C[105],R1C[105],C[100],R1C[100],C[96],""=""&RC[-2])"
End Sub
```